# Running Slim Framework in a folder of a subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, slim

I have set up a subdomain for my API `api.server.com`. I can run my app here but I want to run it in a folder of this subdomain specifically v1. When I try this I just get `404`.

I have modified my `.htaccess` with a multiple of paths all the way back to root with no joy.

```
   RewriteEngine On

   # Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
   # If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
   # absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
   #
   # RewriteBase /
   RewriteBase /all/the/way/back/to/root/www/api/v1/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```

I have tried every posibilty here.

```
  /all/the/way/back/to/root/www/api/v1/
  /the/way/back/to/root/www/api/v1/
  /way/back/to/root/www/api/v1/
  /back/to/root/www/api/v1/
  /to/root/www/api/v1/
  /root/www/api/v1/
  /www/api/v1/
  /api/v1/
  /v1/
```

But still get 404. Any suggestions to solve this?

This is the actual .htaccess for www/api/v1

```
  RewriteEngine On

  # Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
  # If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
  # absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
  #
  # RewriteBase /
  RewriteBase /api/v1/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```

I want to use the main domain as the api website

running the below script

```
  <?php 
  //Gets the document root 
  $root = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") ; 
  Echo $root; 
  ?>
```

gives me `/var/www/domainname.com/web`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much a solution as a work around. Just preceded each route with v1 so a route that was `/items/` was changed to `/v1/items/`

Answer (score 0):

Place the following `.htaccess` code inside `www/api`. Remove the `.htaccess` inside `v1`.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ v1/index.php [L]

RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```

I'm assuming that `/www` is your website's `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` directory.

---

Since, you're accessing your site as `api.server.com/v1`, try this `web/api/v1/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteBase /v1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```

Comment: see question for reply

Comment: You said your app works fine at api.server.com. Did you mean with files being served from /api dir? and where was your htaccess located then? In /www or /www/api?

Comment: files will be served from /api/v1/ there is an .htacces in api and v1

Comment: the .htaccess in /api/ has a RewriteBase / if that helps

Comment: I'm assuming your dir structure is `/var/www/domainname.com/web/api/v1`. Is it correct?

Comment: Strangly I get /var/www/domainname.com/web as root path for sub.domain.com and sub.domain.com/v1

Comment: Your solution gives me an Apache 404 rather than a slim 404

Comment: What url did you use?

Comment: api.domainname.com/v1/

Comment: Oh, now I get you. You want to version your api! I thought you still wanted to access it as `api.server.com` while keeping the files at `/api/v1`. Anyway, does the site work if you go to `api.server.com`?

Comment: Yes it did - forgot to add RewriteEngine On. it does work at `api.server.com`, `api.server.com/v1` has a slim 404 `api.server.com/v1/route` has an Apache 404